# Сложение массивов ArrayList в java

Tags: java, массивы

Как сложить красиво два массива, так чтобы элементы не повторялись?

```java
ArrayList<Point> cells1 = get_move_place(x,y,fig_id);
ArrayList<Point> cells2 = get_eat_figures(x,y,fig_id);
```

Point - это координаты точки на экране.

Comment: Используйте интерфейс `Set`

Comment: спасибо, нашла такое решение пока: ArrayList<Point> cells1 = get_move_place(x,y,fig_id);
        ArrayList<Point> cells2 = get_eat_figures(x,y,fig_id);
        cells1.addAll(cells2);
        HashSet<Point> cells3 = new HashSet(cells1);
        ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>(cells3);

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использвоать Java 8 Stream Api для выполнения операции `distinct`:

```java
ArrayList<Point> cells3 = new ArrayList<>();
cells3.addAll(cells1);
cells3.addAll(cells2);

List<Point> collect = cells3.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Одним стримом это можно сделать: собираем из нескольких листов один [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), либо если нужен именно [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), тогда используем [`distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--):

```java
List<String> cells1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "f");
List<String> cells2 = Arrays.asList("a", "d", "c", "b");
List<String> cells3 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

// собираем сет
Set<String> cells4 = Stream.of(cells1, cells2, cells3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// собираем отсортированный лист
List<String> cells5 = Stream.of(cells1, cells2, cells3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .distinct().sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(cells4); // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
System.out.println(cells5); // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<Point> cells1 = get_move_place(x, y, fig_id);
ArrayList<Point> cells2 = get_eat_figures(x, y, fig_id);
ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>(cells1);

for (Point x : cells2) {
    if (!list.contains(x))
        list.add(x);
}
```

Вроде такой вариант чуть более читаем, чем перекидывание из листа в сет и обратно.